# Changing UV of model imported in Xna

Tags: xna

Is it possible to change UV(texture coordinates) of model(.fbx) in Xna. and I know i can break model into mesh and mesh into meshpart, so can i also break meshpart in to vertices. pls explain

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer; It is possible.

Longer;
What are you trying to do?

- Just want to shift the texture a bit: You can do this by writing a shader that has a parameter UVOffset of type float2 that you add to the existing TexCoord.
- Want to redo it completely: I am not sure this is the kind of thing you would want to do in XNA. You might want to consider editing the model in a 3d-modelling software.
- I want to anyways: The Model has a property called Meshes. each ModelMesh has a property MeshParts. Each MeshParts has a VertexBuffer. Each VertexBuffer has a GetData-Method.

In short, you can fetch the Vertices from the VertexBuffer of a MeshPart, modify them as you wish, and the use the VertexBuffer.SetData-method to apply your changes.

If you tell us what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to give more specific help :)

Edit:
Example based on hlsl found in this thread: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/1407/72515.aspx

insert after 'texture Texture;':

```
float2 UVMultiplier;
```

replace 'output.TexCoord = input.TexCoord;' with:

```
output.TexCoord = input.TexCoord * UVMultiplier;
```

Comment: I want to apply tiling texture to meshes. I learn that if i set UV greater then 0-1, and address mode is set to wrap then texture repeats itself. So i was trying Change UV of modelmeshes

Comment: In that case I would go with option 1, writing a shader for it. But in stead of offsetting the existing UV, you should multiply (and call it UVMultiplier). that way, if your original texture is just streched, you can tell it to tile x times in each directions just by setting the UVMultiplier-parameter to [2, 4] to tile 2 times in the  U direction and 4 times in the V direction

If you just want it to tile the same number of times in each direction, you can use one float instead of a float2. Works the same way :)

Comment: can you give an example, only the shader part

Comment: In top, declare shader parameter:
float2 UVMultiplier; //basicly a Vector2 in XNA-terms.  
  
in Vertex-shader, you multiply the texcoord from the vertex by UVMultiplier before outputing it:  
out.texCoords = texCoords * UVMultiplier;